# Airflow 2.5.2 SQLAlchemy issue resists although the the version requirement is met in the environment

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow

I recently decided to explore Airflow but I am facing some messages if not errors.
I was able to skip most of errors and start airflow on localhost.
But the SQLAlchemy issue is still resisting on my terminal.

I ran  `airflow standalone` command to start with ease.
but this following warning is continuously spammed in terminal

`/opt/anaconda3/envs/portfolio/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/base.py:49 MovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)`

I checked versions, here are the versions

```
alembic                                        1.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
anyio                                          3.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
apache-airflow                                 2.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql            1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
apache-airflow-providers-ftp                   3.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
apache-airflow-providers-http                  4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
apache-airflow-providers-imap                  3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite                3.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

```
python                    3.10.9               h218abb5_2  

sqlalchemy                1.4.46                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy-jsonfield      1.0.1.post0              pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy-utils          0.40.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.1               h6c40b1e_0
```

sqlalchemy version is **`1.4.46`** as shown in the snippets, although the "sqlalchemy<2.0" still is spammed in terminal by scheduler frequently.

I have no Idea if this is important issue, or all is fine and I can ignore them. What is the correct thing to do in this case?

Comment: Airflow ppl are aware of this. You can follow their progress here at https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28723